# REST API parallel bash commands in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, multithreading, express, npm, node-worker-threads

I wanted to create an Express server with NodeJS where an endpoint needs to execute heavy bash operations. But doing this slows down the whole server insanely! For example I created an endpoint `/ping` which just executes the `ping 8.8.8.8` command in the background and returns the result.

If I start 2 parallel requests to the server they block each other and execute one by another:

[blocking requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edzDT.png)

I tried using worker threads but I can't get it done.. Is this even possible in NodeJS? If not ... how could I achieve this?

Comment: You need to show us your server-side code for executing the ping.  Are you using a blocking call?  If not, this may be caused by the browser itself, not by your server where (in the interest of optimizing caching), if you make multiple identical requests from the browser, it waits for the first one to see if it can just be used (via caching) for the subsequent requests.  You can bypass that by adding a variable query parameter `/ping?id=1` and `/ping?id=2` to each request and then the URLs are no longer identical, but they still go to the same route on your server.

Comment: Worker threads should not be required.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

for the worker threads using parameters fixed the problem in the browser!

however my old code without worker threads did not work:

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  
    /* create new uuid to find xml */
    Object.assign(req.body, {id: uuid()});

    exec(`C:/Progress/DLC117-x32/bin/_progres.exe -b -db ${db} -U ${user} -P ${password} -H ${host} -S ${service} -ld basis -N TCP -T C:/temp -Mm 16384 -cpstream 1252 -cpinternal 1252 -cpcoll BASIC -p pa/procedure.p`,
    (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            logger.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
            res.statusCode = 400;
            res.end(`${error.message}`);
            return;
        }
        if (stderr) {
            logger.log(`error: ${stderr}`);
            res.statusCode = 400;
            res.end(`${stderr}`);
            return;
        }
        if(stdout != "") {
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.end(`${stdout}`)
            return;
        }
        
        /* file was successfully written */
        fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'exports', req.body.id + '.xml'), (err, data) => {
            if(err) {
                logger.log(`xml-read-error: ${err}`);
                res.end(`${err}`);
                return;
            }  
            res.end(xmlParser.toJson(data));
        });         
    });
});
```